# Custom array to arraylistview in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have custom array in my Yii 2 controller and I have to show in list view in view.

```
$arr = ['ABC.txt','DEF.txt','HKL.txt','ADS.txt','DDF.txt'];
 //this array pass from controller to view
```

Comment: How far have you got? What is your excat issue? We would need to see more code before we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP MAGIC:

```
    $arr = ['ABC.txt','DEF.txt','HKL.txt','ADS.txt','DDF.txt'];
    $formattedArray = [];
    foreach($arr as $fileName) {
        $formattedArray[] = ['name' => $fileName];
    }
```

Define an `ArrayDataProvider`:

```
    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $formattedArray,
    ]);
```

Pass it to view:

```
return $this->render('yourView', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
```

In yourview.php:

```
<?= 
   ListView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]); 
?>
```

Comment: But my array is not associative its numeric array, I need help for show this data to view

Answer (score 0):

When you render your view, you have to send this array there:

```
$this->render('yourView', ['arr' => $arr]);
```

And then, in view, you can simply foreach this array and display in list.
Also, you musy specify what is your $arr - like:

```
/* @var $arr Array */
```